# :confirm in rails not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to, button-to

I just started coding in ruby on rails and I've been following a guide which is using a more outdated version of rails than I am using.  I am using 3.2.12

This is my code:

```
<%= button_to 'Destroy', product, :method => "delete", :confirm => 'Are you sure?'  %>
```

From what I understand, these are symbols that are passed to rails, which is then converted to either an html or javascript action that then pops up the message box and deletes the object if applicable.  The above code destroys the object, but it does not pop up the confirm box.  Why is this?   Also, I had the above as the following at first:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', product, :method => "delete", :confirm => 'Are you sure?'  %>
```

The confirm box is not popping up under any circumstance, using link_to or button_to.  Below is the html rendered when inspected using Chrome's inspector.  jquery and jquery-ujs are loaded into the  as well, so I'm not sure where to go from here.

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="delete">
<input data-confirm="Are you sureeee?" type="submit" value="Destroy">
<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="Q2xicqELHYHtrwarbtPBe5PT2bZgWV5C+JdcReJI8ig=">
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I had to add my confirm attribute inside the data attribute to get it to work.  I am using rails 4 with bootstrap.  I hope this helps someone else who has that issue.

```
link_to 'Delete', @rule, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this alert?' }
```

Comment: Worked for me using Rails 4 and Foundation. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me on Rails 6. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

This relies on jQuery, ensure you have the following:

in your Gemfile

```
group :assets do
  gem 'jquery-rails'
end
```

in your assets/javascripts/application.js file, before the line `//= require_tree .`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Comment: I have both of the tags you're referring to, but it still does not pop up the confirm box

Comment: I suppose you `bundle install`and restarted your rails server?

Comment: how can I test if javascript is working?  I don't think it is, and I think this is the problem.  I'm just not sure what's causing it.

Comment: Yes, I have run bundle install and restarted server.  No luck.  I have also noticed that nothing comes up in the console when debugging with chrome and clicking the button that's supposed to pop up the :confirm.  Also, my gemfile.lock displays jquery-rails (2.2.1).  Is there something else I may be missing?

Comment: Also, when I run view source on the page, this is the HTML I get for that button.

<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="delete">
<input data-confirm="Are you sureeee?" type="submit" value="Destroy">
<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="Q2xicqELHYHtrwarbtPBe5PT2bZgWV5C+JdcReJI8ig=">

Comment: Do you have the javascript_include_tag in your template?

Comment: @Fred this is in my template: <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>

Comment: Sounds good. At this point, I'd use some browser based debugger like Firebug to examine the page after it loaded and see what jQuery did to the link element.

Comment: @Fred please see revised question with added code from Chrome's inspector.  Everything looks like it's added fine.  jquery.js and jquery-ujs.js are in the header, and I am receiving no bugs in the console when rendering the page.  I'm not sure where to go from here and why this still isn't working.

Comment: And when I said header, I meant the <head> tag.

Answer (score 6):

The difference between link_to and button_to is the HTTP verb. link_to issues GET requests and button_to issues POST requests. With the RESTful routing, the `delete` action is a POST request to *controller/id*. If you issue a GET to *controller/id*, it is dispatched to the `show` action.

AIUI, link_to with anything other than the GET verb is a Bad Idea. One, right-clicks don't preserve the verb. Two, you don't want bots crawling the page to follow the link and thereby trigger the `delete` action even though you probably need to be logged in to actually modify the database.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.  Very informative and makes a lot more sense now.  However, I am still curious on how to get the :confirm to pop up.  This is still not working for me.

Answer (score 4):

Feel pretty dumb, but adblock was blocking the message box.  Sorry about that.  All is well now, I just disabled adblock.

Answer (score 3):

In Rails 7.0.4.3 it got changed and you can now use link using `turbo-method`

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', article_path(article), data: { "turbo-method": :delete, 'turbo-confirm': "Are you sure" } %></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete something with confirmation box in **rails 7**, you may try this one:

With `button_to` (more prefered IMHO):

```
<%= button_to 'Destroy', product, method: :delete,
  form: {data: {turbo_confirm: 'Are you sure?'}} %>
```

This will render an HTML form tag which sends a `POST` request on submit (after confirmation) but with a hidden `_method` attribute with 'delete' value. So that rails will treat this request as if it has a `DELETE` method.

It will be routed to `products#destroy` (or whatever your routes are saying).

With `link_to`:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', product,
  data: {turbo_method: :delete, turbo_confirm: 'Sure?'} %>
```

This will render a simple `a` tag with `data-turbo-method` and `data-turbo-confirm` attributes. Clicking this link will trigger a confirmation box and if "OK" is chosed, a real `DELETE` request will be sent.

If you want to end `destroy` action in your controller with a `redirect_to`, some browsers will redirect to a new location with `DELETE` method (causing errors), so make sure to add `status: :see_other` parameter, like the [guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#deleting-an-article) suggests.

Answer (score 0):

I have a pop-up blocker running in Chrome. I just whitelisted `http://localhost:3000` and it worked for me.